# Update broke apache

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, virtual-host

I just updated from Ubuntu 8.04 to the newest version and all of a sudden my virtual hosts don't work anymore. I'm not sure what changed, but I know when I type in `localhost` it doesn't go to the directory that I would expect (probably the default /var/www/ but that's not where I keep my projects) and typing in the name of one of my virtual hosts takes me to the same place. How do I get it working again?

Answer (score 1):

You may have added your virtual hosts to `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` or something like this, and the file was overwritten on update (you were prompted!). Check if you still have your virtual hosts in `/etc/apache2/sites-available` (one host per file) and that have valid resolvable symlinks in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`: this is the right way to add them in Ubuntu (I believe, in all Unix systems that's common: a great idea to have them separate rather than piling in a single file!).

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the update sort of reset things back to default. Here's what I did to get it to work (This worked for me on Ubuntu 9.10 Karmic Koala):

1. The localhost directory was set to `/var/www` so to change that you will need to edit the default virtual host config file in /etc/apache2/sites-available. Make sure to change both the `DocumentRoot` and `<Directory >` values.

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
   ```
2. To create a virtual host, create a file in /etc/apache2/sites-available

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite
   ```

   Here's an example of what you should put in the virtual host file:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName myvirtualhostname
       ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/myvirtualhostname-error.log
       CustomLog /var/log/apache2/myvirtualhostname-access.log combined
       DocumentRoot /home/name/Projects/myvirtualhostname/public
       <Directory /home/name/Projects/myvirtualhostname/public>
           Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
       </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. Next you will want to enable your virtual host. You can do so by running the "Apache 2 Enable Site" command with the name of the file you created in `sites-available`:

   ```
   sudo a2ensite mysite
   ```
4. You may also need to add your virtual host name to your `/etc/hosts` file.
5. Now restart Apache for it to take affect:

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
   ```

**Bonus!** If you want to get rid of that message that says "Could not determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName" you can create a config file in `/etc/apache2/conf.d/` called `fqdn` with the value of `ServerName localhost`. You can do this in a single command like this:

```
echo "ServerName localhost" | sudo tee /etc/apache2/conf.d/fqdn
```

For more information, check out [setting up Apache, PHP, and MySQL on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an Ubuntu-specific answer for you, but you just need to check your **httpd.conf** for the *DocumentRoot* and set it as needed. Unless your vhost configs got wiped, then you'd need to recreate them.

Answer (score 0):

This could be DNS related as well.

So what does it say when you say specifically  http://localhost://